# Set iframe height by content with every load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Tried all the solution here and none of them worked for me. 
I want to have iframe like the code below. but I need to set the .iframe-container class height dynamically by iframe content height.
I try every solution on stackoverflow but none of them worked.

```
<style>
.iframe-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
  height: 2000px;
}
.iframe-container iframe {
   border: 0;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top:-120px; 
}
</style>

  <div id="frameid" class="iframe-container" >
    <iframe  src="https://idt-spa.kayako.com/it/" frameborder="0"         
scrolling="no" ></iframe>
   </div>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
    setIframeHeight(document.getElementById('frameid'));
};    
 function setIframeHeight(iframe) {
    if (iframe) {
        var iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow ||     
iframe.contentDocument.parentWindow;
        if (iframeWin.document.body) {
            iframe.height =     
iframeWin.document.documentElement.scrollHeight || 
iframeWin.document.body.scrollHeight;
    }
}
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it to set `position:fixed;` like this:

```css
iframe {
        position:fixed;
        border: none;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
```

```html
    <iframe id="frmid" src="https://idt-spa.kayako.com/it/"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar code that works and I call resizing function with a delay (because frame loads after main onload event is fired)

```
<body onload="window.setTimeout(setIframeHeight, 250)">
```

I ran into a lot of issues while trying to make it work, one of them is setting iframe height oftens throws an error so I catch exception and set height to a pre-defined value using style:

```
iframe.style.height = "750px"
```

Below is the relevant code, we actually have two frames (frmImage and frmAction) that we are trying to match if possible but you should get the idea.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeFrame() {
        try {
            var f = document.getElementById('frmAction');
            var i = document.getElementById('frmImage');
            var h = f.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
            if (h < i.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight)
                h = i.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;

            if ((h < 750) && (s.substring(s.length - 3, 3) == "pdf"))
                h = 750;

            if (f.style.height != h + "px")
                f.style.height = h + "px";

            if (i.style.height != h + "px")
                i.style.height = h + "px";
        }
        catch (err) {
            try {
                i.style.height = "750px"; f.style.height = "750px";
            }
            catch (err1) { }
        }
        window.setTimeout(resizeFrame, 250);
    }
</script>
</head>
    <body style="background-color: white" onload="window.setTimeout(resizeFrame, 250)">
```

Comment: Could you provide me a full example, so I can understand more?